# How to deny all outbound traffic from an AWS EC2 Instance using a Security Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to set an AWS Security Group egress rule which blocks all outbound traffic. It has been known that by default, security groups allow all outbound traffic.

I am using AWS CloudFormation and how should we define the appropriate security egress rule?

Comment: What are you running on the instance to make you want to block all outbound access? Do you still want to connect to the instance (eg to login)? If so, that still involves some outbound access to let you interact with the instance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Security Groups always define ALLOW traffic. There is **no concept of a DENY** for security groups.

Therefore, if you wish to deny all traffic, **simply have an empty Security Group**.

However, please note that Security Groups are **stateful**. This means that, if the Inbound security group permits a connection (eg a request coming into a web server), **the response will be automatically permitted to exit** the server. Therefore, it is only truly blocked if both the inbound and outbound security groups are empty (depending upon your configuration).

Other options for blocking the server are a host-based firewall rule (that is, a configuration within the operating system) or the use of Network Access Control Lists (NACLs) that operate at the Subnet level. NACLs have DENY rules that can block traffic in/out of a Subnet (but not to a specific instance).

**Update**

It turns out that, if no Egress rules are supplied, then the default "Allow All" rule is applied to the security group.

Therefore, you need to supply a rule that does nothing, so that the default rule doesn't apply.

For example:

```
"InstanceSecurityGroup": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "VpcId": {
      "Ref": "VPC"
    },
    "SecurityGroupIngress": [
      {
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "FromPort": "80",
        "ToPort": "80",
        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
      }
    ],
    "SecurityGroupEgress": [
      {
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "FromPort": "1",
        "ToPort": "1",
        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/32"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Hey John, can you elaborate on what you mean by leaving the security group empty? I tried leaving the SecurityGroupIngress and SecurityGroupEgress properties without being defined but I always tend to get the same default behavior of no inbound traffic allowed and all outbound traffic allowed.

Comment: By providing an IPv4 egress rule to `0.0.0.0/32` will this automatically exclude IPv6 egress, or will I need to provide an analogous egress rule for IPv6 as `::/128`?

Answer (score 13):

Even though CloudFormation does not allow an empty `SecurityGroupEgress` or `SecurityGroupIngress` properties, you can trick it by allowing allowing all outbound traffic to localhost only:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: A sample template
Resources:
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties: 
      GroupName: block-outbound
      GroupDescription: Allow http to client host
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 127.0.0.1/32
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      VpcId: !Ref myVPC
```

This will achieve your aim of blocking all outbound traffic.

Comment: Although @JohnRotenstein's answer is excellent and goes into more depth about what's going on behind CloudFormation, I prefer this one as a technical workaround. 127.0.0.1/32 is obviously the loopback address. I had to look up what 0.0.0.0/32 even means. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Security groups aren't intended to block the traffic. They are permissive in nature.
If you want to block the outbound traffic on certain IP/Range then use Access Control on VPC which will block or allow ingress or outgress traffic according to your rules.

Answer (score -2):

In your CloudFormation script, you can include the custom rules under 'SecurityGroupEgress' attribute as shown below.

```
"InstanceSecurityGroup" : {
   "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
   "Properties" : {
      "GroupDescription" : "Allow http to client host",
      "VpcId" : {"Ref" : "myVPC"},
      "SecurityGroupIngress" : [{
            "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
            "FromPort" : "80",
            "ToPort" : "80",
            "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
         }],
      "SecurityGroupEgress" : [{
         "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
         "FromPort" : "80",
         "ToPort" : "80",
         "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
      }]
   }
}
```

For more details check the [AWS UserGuide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html).

Comment: Hi, it is true that you can add rules under SecurityGroupEgress property. My question actually requests for a rule which enables us to prevent any kind of outbound traffic from a security group. By default, it allows all outbound traffic. For example, a rule like the following where all outbound traffic is allowed.
SecurityGroupEgress:
  - IpProtocol: -1
    FromPort: '0'
    ToPort: '0'
    CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Above example only opens port 80 since its defined and yes, if not specified, it will fall into default allowing all outbound traffic.

Comment: Yeah, I do understand your example but it will still open port 80. I am looking for a rule which opens nothing. Opposite of default behavior when no egress rules are defined. Please check my first comment where I have defined a rule which opens all. Something of that nature which closes all.

Comment: At the moment, there is no way to deny all as far as I know. As an alternative you can enable ICMP with port value of -1 to allow all the codes for outbound.